# Setting string values to Viso shapedata

Tags: c#, visio

I have a visio shape with shape data column `Prop.Name` of type string
when i try to set its value using
`Visio.Cell propCell = _shapeList[i].get_Cells("Prop.Owner");

 propCell.FormulaForceU = "asd";`

I get an error: `#NAME?`

This does not happen if i pass a numeric string .
How can i pass characters other than number ?

Comment: Have you tried double quotes? ...FormulaForceU = "\"asd\"";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
propCell.FormulaForceU = "\"asd\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to update the shape property value with the normal string as like 'Set Value' it gives error `#NAME?`.

After giving

`c.Formula ="\"Set Value\"";`

it begins to work.